# What are the licensing terms for Portal 2's soundtrack?

Tags: portal-2

I am building a game and would like to reuse a song from the [Portal 2 soundtrack](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/music.php).

But while it's free as in free beer, I can find no information on *licensing*.

What are the licensing terms for reuse of the music?

Comment: As @murgatroid99 stated in [your meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/reasons-for-questions-of-this-type-to-be-downvoted), this question is off-topic for Arqade. Due to this I'm voting to close.

Comment: No worries, thanks for linking to the meta question as explanation. I'll try to avoid off-topic questions in future.

Comment: I think this question belongs better in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed, this is very gamedev. Is it possible for a mod to migrate this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its under copyright and they do not have any posted licensing terms, so unless you have a reason to claim 'fair use' there are no licensing terms.

If you want to license the music and include it in your game, you are going to have to contact valve. http://www.valvesoftware.com/contact/

Comment: Hmm... the project would not rely on the music to function, so I suppose fair use would be a bit of a stretch. I'll contact Valve. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @agryson Being necessary for your project wouldn't make it fair use anyway. It has to be commentary, parody, satire, reporting… that sort of thing.

Comment: True, I mean to say artistically, the music is not the focus of my work, thus I'm not really adding anything to it or commenting on it in any way... the use is a licensable use because I'm just saving myself time and creative effort for which the original author can fairly expect recompense and using it without licensing would thus be 'unfair'. 
But thanks for articulating it better! :-D

Comment: @agryson Aha, I understand now! Yes, that. :)